# Why does /proc/cpuinfo incorrectly report the cpu MHz when overclocked?

Tags: linux, cpu, overclocking

I decided to overclock my AMD Phenom ii X2 560 from 3300 MHz to 3600 MHz. Here are the results of the benchmarks in BOINC, before and after:

```
Windows 7 64-bit:
Normal: 2683 floating point (Whetstone) MIPS, 8215 integer (Dhrystone) MIPS per CPU
Overclocked: 2903 floating point (Whetstone) MIPS, 8618 integer (Dhrystone) MIPS per CPU

Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit:
Normal: 3567 floating point (Whetstone) MIPS, 15851 integer (Dhrystone) MIPS per CPU
Overclocked: 3856 floating point (Whetstone) MIPS, 17097 integer (Dhrystone) MIPS per CPU
```

For some reason, even though there's a noticeable increase, /proc/cpuinfo still reports the frequency as being 3300 MHz. Same if I use 'sudo dmidecode --type processor'. However, Open Hardware Monitor under Windows reports everything correctly. Can anyone tell me why this is?

Edit: I should add that I was using my motherboard's "AI Tuner" feature, which was increasing the base clock speed rather than the multiplier. Now that I've done it manually using the CPU multiplier it seems to report it correctly, but I'm still curious as to why it was wrongly reporting the stock speed originally.

Comment: You didn't include the output you are asking about! Show us exactly what you saw in `/proc/cpuinfo` and `demidecode`. (My guess is that you were expecting the processor's *name* to change, which of course it won't.)

Answer (score 0):

It usually shows an internal frequency divisor's value, not the actual frequency feeded out : there's no frequency meter is built-in in CPU and motherboard. It's actually a shame :(